# Magento2.3.5 Di Compile Breaks custom module admin grid

Tags: module, grid, magento2.3.5

I have an issue whether in developer or production when I run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setActive() on bool in /var/www/vhosts/dev.test.com/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:27 Stack trace: #0`  When code `$resultPage->setActiveMenu('Vendor_Module::entity');` then I get a blank page 200 ok There is nothing in `exception.log`

If I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` after `di:compile` then * is ok and the grid displays.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that the problem was in my controller name `index.php` it and once I fixed everything worked ok so My file had to be `Index.php` instead

Comment: Please mark this as 'answered' as you found the solution.